# Understanding Java bit-wise compliment (~) usage

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

This was a problem to get the modulo 10 (%10) of a product of given two numbers. since the numbers are too large they are given as Strings.

a solution will be,

```
int modulo10(String a, String b) {
    return (a.charAt(a.length()-1)-48)*(b.charAt(b.length()-1)-48)%10;
}
```

And I found a solution as below by someone else.

```
int modulo10(String a, String b) {
    return ~-~a.charAt(a.length()-1)*~-~b.charAt(b.length()-1)%10;
}
```

can someone help me to understand how it will give the required correct output.

Comment: why down-vote this ? can they give a reason so that we can modify the mistakes and correct them.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but: "Can you help me understand" is a vague question. It doesn't explain what about it you don't understand, and doesn't explain what you do (which is relevant, because it is not then necessary to spend time explaining those things in an answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you boil it down, what you are asking is why this works:

```
int modulo10(char ca, char cb) {
  return (~-~ca * ~-~cb) % 10;
}
```

assuming it is called with the last character of each of the strings.

Consider what `'0'` is mapped to by `~-~c`:

- `'0' == 48`
- `~c => ~48 == -49`
- `-~c => -(-49) == 49`
- `~-~c => ~49 == -50`

Similarly for `'1'`:

- `'1' == 49`
- `~c => ~49 == -50`
- `-~c => -(-50) == 50`
- `~-~c => ~50 == -51`

etc. So the characters `0-9` are being mapped to ints `-50, -51, ... -59` etc.

So then, you are just multiplying two of these mapped numbers together - both are negative, so the result is positive; taking modulo 10 gives the "correct" answer.

This looks like a "smart a**" trick, which is just totally unclear to anybody reading it.

Your approach - aside from the fact you could use `'0'` instead of literal `48` - is much easier to understand, and probably more efficient.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation. well this solutions had to be small as possible. (reduce the number of characters used). that is why '48' is used instead of zero's char representation. But thank you for pointing that also. :)